# How do i print a block of strings in one line in java

Tags: java

I'm new to java and i found an activity that needs you to print a block of strings based on a count of a loop.
The input should be:

```
 Input Format:
     2
     1
     3
```

And the output must be:

```
    *     *
   **    **
  ***   ***
 ****  ****
***** *****

    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****

    *     *     *
   **    **    **
  ***   ***   ***
 ****  ****  ****
***** ***** *****
```

I'm having a hard time doing this because i can't print it in one line.
Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    int num1, num2, num3;
      num1 = Integer.parseInt (sc.nextLine ());
      num2 = Integer.parseInt (sc.nextLine ());
      num3 = Integer.parseInt (sc.nextLine ());

    String barricade = "      *\n"
                     + "     **\n" 
                     + "    ***\n" 
                     + "   ****\n" 
                     + "  *****\r";

    for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++)
    {
       System.out.print(barricade);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: and what the 's' is?

Comment: sorry. That's supposed to be 'barricade'

Comment: Try [System.out.printf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

Comment: @LHCHIN no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working script:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
String[] lines = {"      *", "     **", "    ***", "   ****", "  *****"};
int input = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
for (int i=0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j < input; ++j) {
        System.out.print(lines[i]);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

We can use a nested loop here, where the outer loop iterates over the lines of the triangle, and the inner loop controls how many triangles get printed on each line.  For an input of 3, this generated:

```
      *       *       *
     **      **      **
    ***     ***     ***
   ****    ****    ****
  *****   *****   *****
```

Comment: "We can use a nested loop here, where the outer loop iterates over the lines of the triangle, and the inner loop controls how many triangles get printed on each line."
This is what i really figuring out, but i can't pull off the code.

Comment: Well now you have two answers which are doing that `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

You're very close to a working solution now, instead of making `barricade` a `String` with embedded new lines; make it an array. I also would prefer `sc.nextInt()` to hardcoding three calls to `Integer.parseInt()` and I would further make `num1` - `num3` an array. Like,

```
int[] nums = { 2, 1, 3 }; // { sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt() };
String[] barricade = {
        "      *",
        "     **",
        "    ***",
        "   ****",
        "  *****" };
for (int num : nums) {
    for (String line : barricade) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            System.out.print(line);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```